# Speeding up loop in python

Tags: python, numpy

I running into some  performance problems and I would appreciate a quick look at this.

I'm reading frequency domain data and I need to make a data cube for compensating the start frequencies in time domain.

The way I do this now is:

```
compdata = [[np.exp(t_range*sflist[y]) for y in x] for x in sfcube]
```

where

```
t_range = 1j*2*np.pi*time_axis_ns
time_axis_ns = np.array([x*delta_time_ns for x in xrange(number_of_points_for_fft)])
sflist = array([ 29500000.,  30500000.])
```

sfcube is a NxM array with indexes for sflist.

Calculating compdata is by far the slowest part of my program now, any ideas for optimization?

Comment: You've tagged the question as `bumpy`, but it seems like you are using a plain python list comprehension for the slowest part. Are `sfcube` and `sflist` numpy array? If so, you could do some clever indexing to vectorize the exponentiation.

Comment: yeah, both sfcube and sflist are numpy arrays

Comment: `compdata = np.exp([[(t_range*sflist[y]) for y in x] for x in sfcube])` this should be faster. if you use the function on the whole numpy list or numpy array at once, it will iterate in C and will be much faster than python iterations.

Answer (score 1):

Quick win would be to parallelize it across all your CPU cores (+HT if available) using multiprocessing module.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
pool = Pool(16)  ## use total number of cores, x2 if HT is supported.

def f(y):
    return np.exp(t_range*sflist[y])

compdata = [pool.map(f, x) for x in sfcube]
```

Of course this will get you 4-fold to 16-fold speed improvement (depending on number of cores). Still, if that's not good enough, you need to figure out how to do that with vector/matrix operations.

Answer (score 1):

Here's your calculation and an alternative, more numpythonic take on it:

```
compdata = [[np.exp(t_range*sflist[y]) for y in x] for x in sfcube]
compdata2 = np.take(np.exp(sflist[:, None] * t_range), sfcube, axis=0)
```

With this sample data set based on your question:

```
sfcube = np.random.randint(2, size=(100, 100))
delta_time_ns = 100
number_of_points_for_fft = 1024
time_axis_ns = np.array([x*delta_time_ns for x in xrange(number_of_points_for_fft)])
t_range = 1j*2*np.pi*time_axis_ns
sflist = np.array([ 29500000.,  30500000.])
```

I get these timings:

```
In [3]: %timeit compdata = [[np.exp(t_range*sflist[y]) for y in x] for x in sfcube]
1 loops, best of 3: 1.76 s per loop

In [4]: %timeit compdata2 = np.take(np.exp(sflist[:, None] * t_range), sfcube, axis=0)
10 loops, best of 3: 72.2 ms per loop
```

That's a 20x speed-up, although your result will change, depending on the actual sizes of `sflist` and `sfcube`. And what you get is a 3D numpy array, not a list of lists of arrays, although they are interchangeable in most settings, and of course:

```
In [5]: np.allclose(compdata, compdata2)
Out[5]: True
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Python-psyco library

http://psyco.sourceforge.net/ 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psyco

or any other similar library

It may speed up your program.

Comment: on March 12, 2012, Psyco was announced to be "unmaintained and dead" :/

Answer (score 0):

If you have an array of indices, you can use it to vectorize the calculation:

```
In [1]: a = numpy.random.random((4,4))

In [2]: a
Out[2]: 
array([[ 0.08746418,  0.57716752,  0.85863208,  0.42931856],
       [ 0.90259153,  0.19590983,  0.73075288,  0.88976529],
       [ 0.71843135,  0.0169308 ,  0.98336314,  0.22227009],
       [ 0.93776916,  0.58943769,  0.55040806,  0.92192396]])

In [3]: a[0]
Out[3]: array([ 0.08746418,  0.57716752,  0.85863208,  0.42931856])

In [7]: index=[(0,1), (0,1)]

In [8]: a[index]
Out[8]: array([ 0.08746418,  0.19590983])

In [9]: a[index] = 100*a[index]

In [10]: a[index]
Out[10]: array([  8.74641837,  19.59098276])
```

This is usually much faster than using Python lists. Note that a is a NumPy array from the start, and the the indices I use are in the form `a[list_of_rows, list_of_columns]`

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you can create your `time_axis_ns` array using:

```
time_axis_ns = np.arange(number_of_points_for_fft)*delta_time_ns
```

Then rather than you iterating over indices in sfcube:

```
sflist[sfcube]
```

Should give the same result. Then do your `np.exp(t_range*` on the result of this.